# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(apache.httpcomponents) uses lazy or eager initialization for maxTotal and defaultMaxPerRoute?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Apache HttpComponents PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager uses what sort of initialization technique for pooled connection(maxTotal and defaultMaxPerRoute). Does it initializes all the threads lazily during initilization?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Connections are always created upon request, never in advance.

One can warm-up the connection pool however with a series of HEAD or GET requests.